If I do random walks on recurrence relations over $\mathbb F_2$, what do I get? Some kind of discrete version of stochastic calculus?
Context:
The other day I investigated a special case of recurrence relations that was an iterated running xor on bit streams which I had tried connecting to differential operators and differential equations. A nice answer by Robert pointed me in the direction of recurrence relations over the finite field $\mathbb F_2$.

I proceeded to implement a codec for prediction using such families of recurrences.
$$x_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{31} c_{k} \cdot x_{n-k}$$
I suppose we can view this as a scalar product of vectors $\mathbb F_2 ^ {32}$ where $32$ is a nice number that fits computer integer and bit-arithmetic.
Now imagine we have a set of such ${\bf c} = [c_0, \cdots ,c_{31}]$ vectors from which we can select to predict. And that we assign for each $n$ a vector from this set. We want to assume that we can make a division of $n$ so that we get a division of the integers in a distinct non-overlapping sets $\{n_{k_1}, \cdots, n_{k_2}-1\}, \{n_{k_2}, \cdots, n_{k_3}-1\}, \cdots$ where for each n in the set is assigned one and the same such $c$ to predict with.
What kind of mathematics should I look into if I want to view the switch that occurs at these boundaries $n_{k_1}$,$n_{k_2}$ et.c. as some kind of a random walk?
For continuous variables I suppose stochastic calculus and stochastic processes would be a reasonable choice, but as we are working over $\mathbb F_2$ I am kind of at a loss of intuition.

You should probably link the "nice answer by Robert". And I must admit that I am not familiar with what a "codec for prediction" is and would benefit with some kind of explanation or at least a link to one.

I added a link now. A codec for prediction is a machine that given a sequence of x searches for c which approximates or fulfills the recurrence relation for parts of the sequence. Similar as to given a function on a continuous domain : to find a differential equation which describes it on some interval.

So the implication that the distinct non-overlapping sets will be of length >> 1 is due to the values of $c$ being predictors of subsets of the $x$ sequence which overlap?

Yes I think one would prefer to find as long such intervals as possible. The applications I have in mind so far are mostly related to data compression. Longer intervals mean that we can get away with fewer bits representing the total number of intervals on average. There will be a tradeoff for number of incorrectly predicted bits which we also need to encode and transmit. But if we use too short intervals we may not get any compression at all because we need to be able to select between several different c and this would in the general case cost at least a few bits.

If I understand correctly, there is a distinct asymmetry between 0 and 1 in your framework. Any $c$ predicts the constant 0 sequence perfectly, but only a $c$ with an odd number of 1 bits predicts the constant 1 sequence perfectly.

@RonKaminsky Aha.. Perhaps I should add a coefficient for the constant 1 also. Would it remove the bias towards 0?

SE is perturbed that we use comments for discussion. Do you use chat? And no, it wouldn't remove the bias --- AFAICS, the bias comes from multiplication in $F_2$ favoring zero. Using a bit to flip everything might work, though. BTW, you should probably look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register if you have not done so already.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
